# Joins and/or Sub queries or Ranking functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a table as follows:

| Order_ID | Ship_num | Item_code | Qty_to_pick | Qty_picked | Pick_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 1 | 3000 | 0 | Null |
| 1111 | 1 | 2 | 2995 | 1965 | 2021-05-12 |
| 1111 | 2 | 1 | 3000 | 3000 | 2021-06-24 |
| 1111 | 2 | 2 | 1030 | 0 | Null |
| 1111 | 3 | 2 | 1030 | 1030 | 2021-08-23 |
| 2222 | 1 | 3 | 270 | 62 | 2021-03-18 |
| 2222 | 1 | 4 | 432 | 0 | Null |
| 2222 | 2 | 3 | 208 | 0 | Null |
| 2222 | 2 | 4 | 432 | 200 | 2021-05-21 |
| 2222 | 3 | 3 | 208 | 208 | 2021-08-23 |
| 2222 | 3 | 4 | 232 | 200 | 2021-08-25 |

From this table,
I only want to show the rows that has the latest ship_num information, not the latest pick_date information (I was directed to a question like this that needed to return the rows with the latest entry time, I am not looking for that) for an order i.e., I want it as follows

| Order_ID | Ship_num | Item_code | Qty_to_pick | Qty_picked | Pick_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 3 | 2 | 1030 | 1030 | 2021-08-23 |
| 2222 | 3 | 3 | 208 | 208 | 2021-08-23 |
| 2222 | 3 | 4 | 232 | 200 | 2021-08-25 |

I tried the following query,

```
select order_id, max(ship_num), item_code, qty_to_pick, qty_picked, pick_date
from table1
group by order_id, item_code, qty_to_pick, qty_picked, pick_date
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have explained it in this latest question (in the middle), the previous question's top answer was related to returning the rows that had the latest entry "time", I am looking for the max(ship_num) and all rows related to it.

Comment: You don't really *explain*, @Mupp, but I like I commented, this should be an edit to your original question, *not* a repost

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I actually tried editing first. I will keep that in mind for next time. I am really a new user of stack overflow. Sorry, again.

Comment: I feel that actually, *the latest ship_num information* is *the ship_num corresponding to the latest pick_date*, am I wrong? In this case, `max()` function could be place on this date, an a 'simple' group by should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Hi Christophe, in the above example, there are two cases of latest ship_num = 3 for the same order 2222, the pick_dates are different for both, so a max() on pick_date will not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `max(ship_num)` is a good idea, but you should use the analytic version (with an `OVER` clause).

```
select *
from
(
  select t.*, max(ship_num) over (partition by order_id) as orders_max_ship_num
  from table1 t1
) with_max
where ship_num = orders_max_ship_num
order by order_id, item_code;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this using the DENSE_RANK().

**Query**

```
;with cte as (
    select rnk = dense_rank()
       over (Partition by order_id order by ship_num desc)
        , *
    from table_name
)
Select *
from cte
Where rnk =1;
```

Comment: could you please explain your choice of what appear to me a complex query regarding the question? And there is no date in this query, where as I understand our friend is looking for the *latest* ship_num... Am I wrong? I have to recognize that I'm surprised by the answers, I would certainly not have look for the answer in this kind of direction, and I'm wondering if I really understood the question :-/ Thanks for details =)

Comment: @Christophe: While "latest ship num" is a bit confusing, I think it becomes clear in the request that the "greatest ship num" is meant. The OP explicitly mentions "not the latest pick_date", they use max(ship_num) themselves, and the expected result shown confirms that.