# Ranking functions and Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate, ranking-functions

I have the following tables.

Order_det

| Ord_num | item_code | Unit_sales_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 50 |
| 1111 | 2 | 40 |
| 1111 | 3 | 30 |
| 1111 | 4 | 20 |
| 1111 | 5 | 10 |
| 2222 | 3 | 30 |

Pick_det

| Ord_num | Shipment_num | Item_code | Qty_to_pick | Qty_picked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 1111 | 2 | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 1111 | 3 | 2 | 100 | 100 |
| 2222 | 3 | 3 | 200 | 200 |

I want the table as follows,

| Ord_num | Shipment_num | Item_code | Qty_to_pick | Qty_picked | Unit_sales_price | Total_price (Unit_sales_price*Qty_picked) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 3 | 2 | 100 | 100 | 40 | 4000 |
| 2222 | 3 | 3 | 200 | 200 | 30 | 6000 |

With the help of this community, I found a very similar answer i.e,
Link to that answer, [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69001585/joins-and-or-sub-queries-or-ranking-functions)

```
    select *
from
(
  select t1.*, max(shipment_num) over (partition by ord_num) as orders_max_ship_num
  from pick_det t1
) with_max
where shipment_num = orders_max_ship_num
order by ord_num, item_code;
```

My question is,
where do I join the Order_det table to get the Unit_sales_price value to the already retrieved max shipment_num rows from pick_det table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply base a query on yours:

```
with s as
(
  select *
  from
  (
    select t1.*, max(shipment_num) over (partition by ord_num) as orders_max_ship_num
    from pick_det t1
  ) with_max
  where shipment_num = orders_max_ship_num
)
select
  s.ord_num, s.shipment_num, s.item_code, s.qty_to_pick, s.qty_picked,
  od.unit_sales_price, od.unit_sales_price * s.qty_picked as total_price
from s
join order_det od on od.ord_num = s.ord_num and od.item_code = s.item_code
order by s.ord_num, s.item_code;
```

Or you apply the join right away:

```
select
  s.ord_num, s.shipment_num, s.item_code, s.qty_to_pick, s.qty_picked,
  od.unit_sales_price, od.unit_sales_price * s.qty_picked as total_price
from
(
  select t1.*, max(shipment_num) over (partition by ord_num) as orders_max_ship_num
  from pick_det t1
) s
join order_det od on od.ord_num = s.ord_num and od.item_code = s.item_code
where s.shipment_num = s.orders_max_ship_num
order by s.ord_num, s.item_code;
```

Answer (score 4):

Im late to the party, as I typed everything up and made sure it ran correctly

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Order_det') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Order_det;
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Pick_det') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Pick_det;

CREATE TABLE #Order_det (Ord_num INT, item_code INT, Unit_sales_price INT);
CREATE TABLE #Pick_det(Ord_num INT, Shipment_num INT, Item_code INT, Qty_to_pick INT, Qty_picked INT);

INSERT INTO #Order_det (Ord_num, item_code, Unit_sales_price)
VALUES
(1111,  1,  50),
(1111,  2,  40),
(1111,  3,  30),
(1111,  4,  20),
(1111,  5,  10),
(2222,  3,  30)

INSERT INTO #Pick_det (Ord_num, Shipment_num, Item_code, Qty_to_pick, Qty_picked)
VALUES
(1111,  1,  1,  100,    100),
(1111,  2,  1,  100,    100),
(1111,  3,  2,  100,    100),
(2222,  3,  3,  200,    200)

SELECT
    OrderDet.Ord_num
    , PickList.Shipment_Num
    , OrderDet.Item_code
    , PickList.Qty_to_pick 
    , PickList.Qty_picked 
    , OrderDet.Unit_sales_price
    , OrderDet.Unit_sales_price * PickList.Qty_picked AS Total_price
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Ord_num
            , MAX(Shipment_num) OVER (PARTITION BY ord_num) AS MaxShipment_Num--
            , Shipment_num
            , Item_code
            , Qty_to_pick 
            , Qty_picked 
        FROM #Pick_det
    ) AS PickList 
    INNER JOIN  #Order_det AS OrderDet
        ON OrderDet.Ord_num = PickList.Ord_num 
        AND OrderDet.item_code = PickList.Item_code
        and PickList.Shipment_num = PickList.MaxShipment_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple technique you could use is by applying analytic function - Dense_Rank which is a window function that assigns a rank to each row within a partition of a result set

I am trying to rank by shipment_num in descending order and then just JOINing on the common column. I have used CTE and sub-query as well:

```
With temp AS(Select * from (SELECT a.*, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ord_num order by shipment_num desc) rnk
from Pick_det a) t where rnk = 1)

Select temp.Ord_num, temp.Shipment_num, temp.item_code, temp.Qty_to_pick, temp.Qty_picked,
temp.qty_to_pick * Order_det.Unit_sales_price total_price
from temp  JOIN Order_det on temp.ord_num = Order_det.ord_num
AND temp.item_code = Order_det.item_code;
```

Your Sub-query would look something like this:

```
Select temp.Ord_num, temp.Shipment_num, temp.Item_code, temp.Qty_to_Pick, temp.Qty_picked,
temp.qty_to_pick * Order_det.Unit_sales_price total_price
from 
(SELECT a.*, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ord_num order by shipment_num desc) rnk
from Pick_det a) temp INNER JOIN Order_det on temp.ord_num = Order_det.ord_num
AND temp.item_code = Order_det.item_code
AND temp.rnk = 1;
```

If you want to learn about dense_rank function, here is the [link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-dense_rank-function/#:%7E:text=The%20DENSE_RANK()%20is%20a,they%20have%20the%20same%20values.)

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30dd2/2)